# Python Bible verse lookup

Tags: python, parsing

I'm fairly new to python and I'm trying to learn. I'm writing a program that will import a text file that contains the king james bible. The user would have to enter in the bible verse for instance gen 1:1 or gen 1:1-10 and it will either display that verse or verses upon raw data input so far I have it to where the program receives the file and splits the data input I'm not sure what features of python I could use to finish this

```
bible = open("kjv.txt" , "r").readlines()
 for line in bible:
  x = line.split("|")
  print "%s, %s, %s" % (x[0], x[1], x[2])
```

a sample of how the text file looks

```
0 | gen 1:1 | In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth. 
1 | gen 1:2 | And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters. 
2 | gen 1:3 | And God said, Let there be light: and there was light. 
3 | gen 1:4 | And God saw the light, that it was good: and God divided the light from the darkness. 
4 | gen 1:5 | And God called the light Day, and the darkness he called Night. And the evening and the morning were the first day. 
5 | gen 1:6 | And God said, Let there be a firmament in the midst of the waters, and let it divide the waters from the waters. 
6 | gen 1:7 | And God made the firmament, and divided the waters which were under the firmament from the waters which were above the firmament: and it was so. 
7 | gen 1:8 | And God called the firmament Heaven. And the evening and the morning were the second day. 
8 | gen 1:9 | And God said, Let the waters under the heaven be gathered together unto one place, and let the dry land appear: and it was so. 
9 | gen 1:10 | And God called the dry land Earth; and the gathering together of the waters called he Seas: and God saw that it was good.
```

Comment: Do "0 |","1 |", etc. indicate new lines?

Comment: I was going to say that you should really use a database (e.g. via [python's sqlite3 library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)) because the Bible is pretty big—but I just downloaded it from [here](http://printkjv.ifbweb.com/) and the whole thing (uncompressed) is only 4.3MB and ~34k lines of text, so even reading the whole thing line-by-line for each query probably wouldn't take long on any modern system. Keep in mind though that dealing with the raw text file isn't going to be the most efficient way of doing this.

Comment: @CodieCodeMonkey do you believe in God?

Comment: @Harold do you believe in relevant questions?

Comment: awesome - thx for rasing this question: it is a crystal clear example how to do a retrival in the bible

Answer (score 6):

```
bibletext = """the bible contents"""

bible = {}
for line in bibletext.splitlines():
    number,bv,contents = line.split(" | ")
    book,verse = bv.strip().split(" ")
    print book
    print bible
    if book in bible:
        bible[book].append([verse,contents])
    else:
        bible[book] = [verse,contents]

print bible
```

This will return a `bible` dictionary, using books as keys (so you can do `bible['gen']`, for example, and get the contents of that book). The contents of a book are stored as a list of lists, like this:

```
[['1:1', 'In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.', ['1:2', 'And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters. ']]
```

In the future, if you need something more specific, please *specify* that in your question.

Comment: It turns out that its receiving AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'splitlines'

Comment: If you're using `bibletext = open("kjv.txt" , "r").readlines()`, then remove the "`.splitlines`", since `.readlines()` pre-splits the lines.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things that you can use to keep pushing forward with this:

Suppose after splitting, you have white space to get rid of:

```
a = " white space on both sides "
b = a.strip()
print b  # "white space on both sides"
```

I suggest putting your data in a dictionary so that you can look it up by chapter and verse

```
bible = {}
for line in bible:
    x = line.split("|")
    bible[x[1].strip()] = x[2].strip()

chapter_verse = raw_input('Enter a chapter and verse: ')
print bible[chapter_verse]
```

Comment: thank you Tom for the new answer - great to see your engagement in pushing it forward. this is a great asset of learning that we benefit.